# When importing a module, how do I specify an interpreter to compile the module?

Tags: python, import, module, pythoninterpreter

I wrote a module (mymodule32.py) that contains a library that only supports 32 bit Python. I want to import this module in a 64 bit Python file (main64.py). But after searching, I realized that if I import the module in 64 bit Python, it will be compiled with the 64 bit interpreter. I will import mymodule32.py in main64.py, but I want to interpret it with a 32 bit interpreter.

I installed Python 3.5 64 bit, and in addition I installed Python 3.5 32 bit under the name py35_32 in the Anaconda virtual environment.
I wrote the pseudo code below I wanted(it does not work, of course).

```
import(interpreter = py35_32) mymodule32
```

Comment: An interesting question: "how do I tell an interpreter to compile something"...

Comment: You can't. The interpreter imports bytecode, not a separate interpreter.

Comment: At most you can run another Python binary as a subprocess, telling it to run a particular piece of code your parent process then communicates with.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I succeeded in calling 32bit Python files using IPC. For those who might need it, I'll put that code below.

import subprocess

subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\hhoon\\.conda\\envs\\py35_32\\python.exe', 'C:\\Users\\hhoon\\PycharmProjects\\AlgoT\\py32\\py32.py'], bufsize=-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you want with `import`. The interpreter is a single process, and can't switch between 64-bit and 32-bit modes.

Your options are to

- Run all your code in a Python 32-bit binary. You can guard against using a 64-bit binary by testing for `sys.maxsize == (2 ** 31 - 1)`.
- Make your library work correctly on a 64-bit interpreter too (just make sure your 32-bit arithmetic is properly masked).
- Run another Python process as a subprocess; that child process would import your module and use some form of IPC (interprocess communication) to pass data and results between the parent 64-bit process and the child 32-bit interpreter. There are no ready-made solutions here, however.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However first option is unavailable; The 32bit library I want to use is provided by the Korean securities API. However, APIs of all securities in Korea were built in the past when using 32bit operating system and have not been upgraded to 64bit so far. So this problem is not in my hands.

Comment: And about the second option, IPC is also in the forefront, but when I did a search, Python's IPC module was very complicated for me.

So I am thinking of a third option that is not working efficiently. It is a way to make both processes communicate with each other by simultaneously running 32bit Python and 64bit Python, and make them read / write csv files at the same time. It's a very simple and primitive way to succeed. However, I expect that if csv files become bigger, the computational resources will be wasted.

Comment: So I will study more about IPC you suggested and if I fail to implement it, I will choose the third option although it is inefficient.

Comment: @Tactile0409: so just run your code with the 32-bit binary. Why do you need to use the 64-bit binary at all?

Comment: This is because I need a tensorflow library that supports only Python 64 bit. I am developing an algorithm trading program that automatically buys / sells stocks stocks through securitie's API based on the analysis of News articles with the tensorflow library. TT